# Updating Form Data Select Box when tabbed

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

I am currently using the following code to update form data before submission.

```
    $('.countyx').change(function(){
            var d=$(this).val();
            $('.countyq').text(d);
        });
```

This works fine if the user selects any change with their mouse, however, if the user uses the arrow keys to navigate the checkbox the 'change' is not registered. Obviously the keyup handler would work but is there any way to implement two handlers at once in a neat, lightweight way?

Comment: Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316283/trigger-change-event-and-keyup-event-in-select-element), similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fn_count = function() {$('.countyq').text($('.countyx').val());}
$('.countyx').change(fn_count).keyup(fn_count);
```

Comment: Superb - great clean code that works perfectly - many thanks. Will rate once the site lets me - in approx 6mins - thanks for the super speedy solution :)

Answer (score 0):

To maintain scope as you have in your example:

```
$('.countyx').change(function() {
    $('.countyq').text($(this).val());
}).keyup(function () { $(this).change(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for this option. All answers have been useful :)